# I have a problem with wine: "path not found" when trying to run install.exe

Tags: wine

I get an error "path not found" when I'm trying to run install.exe

I've tried running `rm .wine` and `winecfg` but can't solve this problem.

```
$ wine  data/Prog./Program/install.exe 
wine: cannot find 'data/Prog./Program/install.exe'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this "Prog." an abbreviation for the real directory name? If no: please try in a directory without a dot at the end. If yes: does the real directory name have spaces, like "My Programs"? Then you have to quote these spaces, i.e. use double quotes or apostrophes, like so:

```
wine 'data/My Programs/Program/install.exe'
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by opening winecfg and adding a directory **H: /home/**.

My Ubuntu version uses this as the root directory name. Your version might use `/root/` or anything else. Just look at the first directory path in the directory for what you are trying to open and add that.

Comment: That worked for me although I simply pressed Autodetect on the Drives tab of winecfg which did the job!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when starting a wine application from the kickoff menu, I had the window "Path not found" that appears again after closing it. This happened after I renamed user name in the linux system.

As written [here](http://www.gamersonlinux.com/forum/threads/lnk-properties.961/), I saw strings of lnk and the old username was baked there. I do not know if it is possible to edit lnk files, but I just fixed that by editing Exec line in desktop file of application (it is in ~/.local/share/applications/) from

```
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/old_username/.wine" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/old_username/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/old_username/Start\ Menu/Programs/CN8000/CN8000\ WinClient.lnk
```

to just

```
Exec='/home/new_username/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Aten/CN8000 WinClient/iClient.exe'
```

If you know how to do it "the right way", please share.